# Casting an UnsafeMutableRawPointer to Multiple Types

Tags: swift

I've got two `class`es that both conform to the same `protocol`:

```swift
class A {}
class B {}

protocol P {}

extension A: P {}
extension B: P {}
```

In addition, I've got a callback closure whose main argument is a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` passed in to some C API function:

```swift
SomeCFunction(…, …, { (pointerToEitherAOrB: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) in
  // Cast pointerToEitherAOrB to either A or B.
})
```

I don't know which of the two `class`es the pointer refers to. Would it still be possible to cast this pointer to the correct type?

My intuition tells me this wouldn't be possible and that I will need to use a `super` `class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a common superclass would be the cleaner approach, but converting to `AnyObject` first seems to work as well:

```
let aOrB = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(pointerToEitherAOrB).takeUnretainedValue()
switch aOrB {
case let a as A:
    print(a)
case let b as B:
    print(b)
default:
    print("Something else")
}
```